# Suitable Chrome driver to use with selenium tests

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-web-driver

I was wandering since there is many chrome drivers available on the nuGet Packages Manager, which one is fitting the best with Selenium tests, does it make any difference at all?

- WebDriver ChromeDriver
- WebDriverChromeDriver
- Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver

**etc...**

Answer (score 1):

I'm using for my >30K lines of code (and 6 different web-sites) UI test project the

> WebDriver ChromeDriver

with version 26.14.313457.1, it's a separate executable that WebDriver uses to control the Chrome browser. Again it requires Chromium/Google Chrome to be installed.